# How can i check number of files selected with Fine Uploader?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I am using manual uploading via Fine Uploader. Now i want to check that file has selected or not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fineuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#fine-uploader')[0],
        request: {
            endpoint: '<?php echo site_url('pl_items/upload_images');?>'
        },
        multiple: true,
        autoUpload: false,
        onLeave: false,
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
            sizeLimit: 5120000 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
        },
        text: { 
            uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select Files' 
        },
        template: '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
                  '<pre class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></pre>' +
                  '<div class="qq-upload-button btn btn-danger">{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
                  '<div class="qq-drop-processing span1"><span>{dropProcessingText}</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></div>' +
                  '<div><ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul></div>' +
                   '</div>',
        callbacks: {
            onComplete: function(id, name, response) {
                $('#frmDetails').append('<input type="hidden" name="pl_item_images[]" value="'+response.file_name+'">');
                //$("#frmDetails").submit();
            }
        },
    });

    $('#submit_button').click(function() {
        fineuploader.uploadStoredFiles();
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you want to check the number of selected files, and why?

Comment: Well I have come across the same problem ! Is it possible to know the total number of images selected and they are rendered/loaded in the preview box (either preview is available or not) ! I want to disable the upload button until all the images are loaded correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you haven't responded to my question, I'll just assume that you want to determine if a file has been selected before you call `uploadStoredFiles` in your click handler.

It's really very simple.  Just make use of the `getUploads` API method.  For example, you could change your click handler to look like this:

```
$('#submit_button').click(function() {
    var submittedFileCount = fineuploader.getUploads({status: qq.status.SUBMITTED}).length;

    if (submittedFileCouunt > 0) {
        fineuploader.uploadStoredFiles();
    }
});
```

A few more things:

- There is no `onLeave` option.  You should remove this from your code.
- The `multiple` option defaults to true.  You can remove this from your code as well.
- You are already using jQuery.  Why aren't you using the Fine Uploader jQuery plug-in?  See the documentation for instructions.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: I'm not that user though hehe, I upvoted you answer, but that's all I can do hehe. Hey any reason why my "qq" variable would not have a .STATUS?

Comment: @SébastienRicher Yes.  The most likely cause is you are using a version of Fine Uploader older than 3.6.  Also, the property is `status`, and not `STATUS`.

Comment: Your code will not work. You have a typo error in variable name "submittedFileCouunt". :P... anyway good answer.

Comment: In my case, there is no form submit button, i have a browse button functionality which uploads selected files then how can i get number of files before starting uploading process? Please suggest me. Thank you.